# Mark a file for a particular purpose in Linux

Tags: linux, filesystems, rhel

In `NTFS`, it is possible to include some information in File attributes, which, when read, can assist in identifying that file for a particular action.

Is there something similar in common `Linux` file systems? I suppose it does boil down to file systems, and not the actual OS?

Essentially, I'd like to mark the file, to be used for a particular purpose, or be ignored for said purpose. One way is to maintain another file with this information, and cross-check with file name, but that increases overhead by quite a bit. Another option is to identify by filename, such as `<_filename>_noupload`, or `<_filename>_shred`. Another option is by keeping files meant for different purposes in different folders, but I don't wish to tinker with file names or their locations if I can help it.

Any other way, I can make the file directly tell me whether it's fit / unfit for some operation by modifying some file related operation? File systems I'm using are `xfs` or `ext4` if it comes to it...

Comment: It sounds like you are talking about [tag:mime-types].

Comment: @Kusalananda  Well, they're all the same type of files, it's just that some files have had some operation performed on them, and are then say, eligible for download, or deletion, or any other action, and some files aren't. While mime-types certainly assist in handling different types of data, I'm not sure how I can implement such a differentiation at a file level..I'd just to say, consume a file, and, without tinkering with file name, mark it as eligible for shredding. mime-types can be used based on file extensions maybe, but then the file name changes a bit...

Comment: You want OS or Filesystem to known and handle semantic of your file ? (e.g. where (in directory) and when  you can create/edit/delete them) I don't think this could done at unix level, you seems to be talking about a workflow.

Comment: @Archemar Well, in `NTFS` there are `extended attributes` which are not interpreted, or aren't used by the filesystem. I suppose once I am ready, I can modify one of these attributes to say "U" which may mean "upload" to my application. In `Linux` too, we have `xattr`. Can a user application modify any `xattr` at will, so it means nothing to file system, but can still be read and interpreted by another user application?

Comment: Looks like you have an answer to test.

Comment: @A.B Answer being my comment? I'm checking, but not being very familiar, I'm having to tip-toe to really ensure that A. I can modify these attributes using an application and B.It does not have any impact besides just being some metadata info which only makes sense to an application reading it.